# which preposition should go with attractive

Tags: prepositions, grammaticality, usage

Normally, people say "I'm attracted to her", "She is attractive to me" to convey that "she is an attractive person". Not that the two words are all that closely related, but attractive seems to be used with the word 'to' often.

But, it arose to me that when there is an attractive option its usually for someone. For instance, "Cultural relativism is an attractive option for people in a time when tolerance is dominant." But when you change the word into to, it sounds awkward. "...is an attractive option to people". Is there something wrong with this or is it just me?

Comment: English-speaking people also say *This is a/the good/bad/only/etc. option for people who...* – what does that tell you about *attractive* in that sentence? Note that in *I'm attracted to her* and *She's attractive to me*, *to* is employed with different meanings, which in turn means it's a coincidence in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, people do not say, 'She is attractive to me', they just say, 'She is attractive', or they use the other option that you used, 'I'm attracted to her.'

Were I recasting your sentence regarding cultural relativism, I would say either:

> In a time when tolerance is dominant, people are attracted to cultural
>   relativism (as an option).

or

> In a time when tolerance is dominant, people find cultural relativism to be an attractive option.

Note: I would probably omit the words in brackets in the first sentence.